# Knockout js multiple bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have multiple grids that I would like to run under a sigle submit button.
Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/aETvS/

I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

```
    self.orders = ko.observableArray(orders);

self.addorder = function() {
    self.orders.push({
        name: "",
        price: ""
    });
};

self.removeorder = function(order) {
    self.orders.remove(order);
};


self.hardware = ko.observableArray(hardware);

self.addhardware = function() {
    self.hardware.push({
        name: "",
        price: ""
    });
};

self.removehardware = function(hardware) {
    self.hardware.remove(hardware);
};


self.save = function(form) {
    alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.orders));
    // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.orders);
};
```

Comment: @downvoters please do not down vote with out specifying your valuable comments.

Comment: That is because the fiddle isn't quite what I'm trying to accomplish. I should of updated it, a better example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/2076/ I'm trying to put multiple observableArray's inside one function (if that is the right way) basically i need more than one foreach (with the add button) contained within one form with one submit button.

Comment: there are many error in your fiddle.. May this fiddle can help what you trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/hr94y/

Comment: That isn't it. Thank you for your code though :) I need multiple grids under a single submit button with KO.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things.

1. Your fiddle does not include knockout.
2. You want to post a form. Add a submit binding to your form.

   data-bind="submit: save"

I have updated your fiddle. I am not seeing an error with the array push however.

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/qMDH5/19/

```
<form class="form-horizontal margin-zero" method="POST" action="http://toolkit.dev/" accept-charset="utf-8" novalidate="novalidate" data-bind="submit: save">
```

Hope that helps.

-Suj

Comment: Forgot to load knockout on that fiddle sorry, I made a few before putting it on this post. However, I know the issue is somewhere in the js I posted on stackoverflow, my js is weak and I'm not sure if I wrote the syntax properly, I just need someone to confirm that it is written according to knockout and javascript.

Comment: When do you get the error? I am assuming here that you are calling a function. From the code you have posted, it looks like there are only two "push" calls and both of them are in a function "addOrders" and "addHardware". The reason you are getting the error is that the array is not defined (that is assuming the code you have posted here is the one you are getting the error on).

Comment: I figure that to be true, could you edit my code with the array defined, or how would I define it?

Comment: I am not completely sure of what your requirements are. Here is a fiddle with how the viewmodel and stuff will look like and how the arrays would be declared. http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/qMDH5/1/

Comment: That is almost it, so instead of save buttons for each line, there should be delete buttons, and one single global save button that includes fields from both services and hardware into json data.

Comment: Is Harware and Orders different? Or does adding a hardware add it to the Orders? Or do you choose something from the Hardware and add it to the orders?

Comment: they are different but within the same form, so if there is data in the hardware and data in the orders and the user hits submit it should use both hardware and orders in the json.

Comment: I have updated it http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/qMDH5/19/ see if this is what you are looking for. Had a small typo in the previous one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26480/discussion-between-sujesh-arukil-and-stephen-harman)